# Mongodb is running out space - how to increase it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My mongo has stopped running:

```
$ sudo systemctl status mongodb.service
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-01-05 02:26:08 GMT; 8min ago
  Process: 27887 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongodb.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 27887 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 05 02:26:08 localhost systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Jan 05 02:26:08 localhost systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 05 02:26:08 localhost systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 05 02:26:08 localhost systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I think probably it is running out of space:

```
$ df -h /var/lib/mongodb/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        38G   38G     0 100% /
```

How can I fix this? Can we increase the the size for it?

I am on Arch Linux.

Comment: That filesystem, `/`, on the device `/dev/root`, is full. You will need to expand your storage or move Mongo somewhere else. How you expand depends on your storage setup and would really be a question for ServerFault or SuperUser.

Comment: @Puddingfox thanks for the reply. So if I increase the capacity of `/dev/root`, then it would be fine?

Comment: Presumably. You should check what is using all that space already. Usually you would put important things in a separate filesystem to prevent other things from taking their space.